# C++ Policy Based Design

Tags: c++, string, templates, stdstring, policy-based-design

What I do not understand in the Alexandrescu **policy based design** is the creation of new types without anything in common where, in my opinion, there is still a lot in common that should be represented somehow.

For example, `std::string` and `std::basic_string<>`: allocator are something very internal and, in my opinion, the code using that class shall not be aware of which allocator that class is using.

BUT since a new type has been created, let's say `std::basic_string_1`, all those methods which are passing around an `std::string&` are basically broken, and I can't see a valid reason why an `std::basic_string<>` with a different allocator shall be considered totally different from an `std::basic_string<>` with another allocator.

My question is: why there is not common parent for every `std::basic_string<>`, so that this problem could be avoided? Generally in my code when I have a `Whatever<T>`, I make it inherits from a `WhateverBase` of some sort, and when `T` is not shown on the public interface of that class, it works greatfully...

Comment: You could use a [`std::experimental::polymorphic_allocator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/polymorphic_allocator) if you need runtime polymorphic allocator support.

Comment: You could avoid some problems and inevitably create some others. It's a trade off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> allocator are something very internal and, in my opinion, the code using that class shall not be aware of which allocator that class is using.

Which is why usually you don't care, and just use `std::string`. Most code doesn't use custom allocators, so it simply isn't a problem.

As Kerrek SB points out in a comment, you have the option of using `std::experimental::pmr::string` which uses a type-erased allocator, so the details of exactly what kind of allocator is used are hidden. That has some run-time cost, but also has some advantages.

More generally, you're right that policy-based designs lead to an explosion of different types that don't interoperate. Sometimes that is a problem (and sometimes it isn't). One approach to dealing with that is to write generic code that doesn't care if it deals with `policy_base_ptr<X, Y, Z>` or `policy_based_ptr<A, B, C>`. Write generic code that uses "some kind of smart pointer" and you don't care about the exact type. That isn't always  an option though, for example when defining an interface, where you often need to use concrete types.

> My question is: why there is not common parent for every `std::basic_string<>`, so that this problem could be avoided? Generally in my code when I have a `Whatever<T>`, I make it inherits from a `WhateverBase` of some sort, and when `T` is not shown on the public interface of that class, it works greatfully...

That means your class is polymorphic, and code that only knows about the base class must pass it by reference. It cannot be passed by value because it will be sliced. That means you have to be careful about object ownership, and care about when the reference is still valid, and who is responsible for destroying the derived type.

That is a perfectly reasonable choice for you to make in your own software, but is not suitable for a general purpose vocabulary type like `std::string`. It is essential that strings can be passed around by value and copied easily.

Comment: I see the drawback of a common base class. Then what about a common base class for the allocator, passed upon object construction when a different behaviour is wanted, so that the allocator is a polymorphic object owned by the instance in which is passed while the std::string is kept as it is? (P.S. I also would like to clarify that std::string is just an example, and that the question is more in general on policy based design, so if you like you can switch on talking about any container if you think it would made a better example)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/polymorphic_allocator is (which you've now been pointed to three times :-)